# How can I correct a reviewer's opinion?

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits

My edit to an answer was accepted by two of the three reviewers, with the third rejecting with a claim that part of my edit was incorrect.

In fact, my proposed edit was entirely and demonstrably correct, and the reason given for rejecting is invalid.

How can I let that reviewer know about their error, and have them change their review to "Accept" - changing stats for both of us?

**Please note:**  This is not the same question as asking for an appeal of an edit that was rejected.  It's asking what I can do about one of the three reviewers, a dissenter who voted against my edit based on their incorrect information.

Comment: once a reviewer has reviewed something they cannot change their mind.

Comment: @Robert they can't, but author of the post can undo the review decision. (Though it's not not relevant here)

Comment: You can hunt them down in chat if they have an account there but be prepared to have some *discussion*. These days those are civil.

Comment: Is it [this edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/115518) you mean? You're putting words in the answer's mouth. That's not the done thing. If you want to say something the answerer didn't say, write your own answer.

Comment: @ale not dupe, the one here is about edits that were **approved**, with a single reviewer rejecting, so asking to undo that even though it didn't affect the final outcome of the review.

Answer (score 7):

> my proposed edit was entirely and demonstrably correct

That is irrelevant to editing someone's post. If you're fixing spelling or perhaps improving how a user is saying something, that's fine. But you're not allowed to say something that the post didn't try to say, no matter how correct that information may be. Everyone has ownership of their posts, even if they're wrong.

If someone has said something incorrect, you have two options: post a comment detailing the error (with the expectation that the user will come back and fix it), or make an answer which provides the correct information.

Comment: One problem: that [same edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/115586) was approved by site moderator. (So obviously, each site has different edit/review standards.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was under the impression that one of the main values of SE was collaboration...

Comment: @Braiam not when it comes to such things, IMO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia"?!

Answer (score 5):

> How can I let that reviewer know about their error, and have them change their review to "Accept" - changing stats for both of us?

Once the review is done, it's done. There's no further communication between editor and reviewers over *that* edit.

But next time you go to propose an edit... Remember that you get the first word:

[image: editor revision comment: Added that TempDB will be automatically encrypted]

That's the comment you left, right? It literally describes the words you typed into the edit itself. Imagine if someone did that in code:

```sql
-- append ' for me to poop on!'
select concat(Name, ' for me to poop on!') ComedyInsult
from AnyOldObject
```

Is that comment helpful? Of course not! You can *read* the line immediately after it; in fact you could've read it faster if the comment wasn't in the way.

Make your revision comment for the same reason you'd leave a comment in code: to explain **why** you're doing that thing that you're obviously doing:

```sql
-- there is no good reason for me to do this. Please, write a better example!
select concat(Name, ' for me to poop on!') ComedyInsult
from AnyOldObject
```

or in your case,

> [image: a note for future readers to avoid implying that sensitive information may remain unencrypted]

Comment: Your point is well taken, and I'll bear it in mind in future edits.  Perhaps the prompt "Edit Summary" suggests "a short version of your edit", and should be changed to "Justification", "Reason for Edit", or something similar.

Comment: Not a bad idea, @Mark - consider posting a feature-request!

Comment: The feature-request I submitted [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312549/change-the-prompt-edit-summary-to-something-more-appropriate?noredirect=1#comment1022722_312549) was not well received.